# UICollectionView with only 1 vertical 'column' still flowing into 2 columns

Tags: ios, iphone

I've created what I thought was a basic UICollectionView using xCode 5, iOS 7, Storyboards,
AutoLayout OFF, however I'm getting strange results.

I had hoped to create a single "column" - that is, all cells stacked vertically, none side-by-side (like a TableView for example):

| 1 |

| 2 |

| 3 |

| 4 |

| 5 |

However, I'm getting 2 columns like this (which I can only see if I scroll horizontally):

| 1 | | 2 |

| 3 | | 4 |

| 5 |

My CollectionView is the same width as my cells,
1 section, no insets, no headers, scroll direction=vertical, layout=Flow.

EDIT: I tried adding 5 cells via the Storyboard and they lined up exactly as I want, but still do not line up when added programatically...

EDIT2: FYI, I also another UICollectionView which works fine - the only difference is that it is 4x4

How can I achieve the 'single column' layout?

Comment: Are you overriding - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ?

Comment: No - should I be doing that? All my cells are the same size and have been set correctly via the Storyboard. I can see them when I scroll horizontally (which I do not wish to do).

Comment: If you are seeing more than 1 cell per row then either something is making your cells smaller thank you think, or something is making you collection view larger than you think. The latter is most likely. Put a breakpoint in viewDidApper and look at your collection view's frame. Is it the size you think it should be?

Comment: Geoff - You Nailed it! Even though I have auto layout off, autosizing was scaling the collectionView because my layout is landscape (even though my other views are fine). I turned off 'scale' in autosize and it's all good - THANKS!

Comment: Geoff - do you want to write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Look into implementing `-(CGSize)collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` of the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. You can adjust your cells based on the collection view bounds. The flow layout is currently taking advantage of the fact that 2 of your cells can fit side-by-side while the device is in landscape orientation.

Another approach is to modify the inset for a section (ie, you can pad such that a single column is all you see) using `-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:`

Comment: I have tried 'sizeForItemAtIndexPath' using the size of the cells, but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to manage your collection view your view controller should follow three protocols:`UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.Which in fact means you need to override:

```
    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return numberOfItems;
    }
    -(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
//configure your cell the way you want
    return cell;
}
```

In order to get one column you must set cell's width same as the width of your collectionView or more but less then (double width of the cell+interitem spacing+insets)

Try this at cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
    CGRect a =cell.frame;
    a = GCRectMake(0,96*[indexPath.item intValue],113,96);
    cell.frame = a;
```

Comment: Yes, I have already done all of that...My collectionView is the same width as my Cells.

Comment: Nope - no change at all.

Comment: I don't really understand  (which I can only see if I scroll horizontally) and direction=vertical.What is the actual direction?

Comment: My collectionView is 113 wide x 276 high. My cells are 113w x 96h (so 4 should be visible at any time). If I set my scrolling to vertical only, I can see cells 1,3,5 (and a blank cell at the bottom). I had to set my scrolling to include horizontal so I could see that cells 2 and 4 were in 'another column'. However, I only want vertical scrolling and all cells (regardless of final count) to be stacked vertically in a single column...

Comment: what about overriding collectionViewContentSize?

Comment: I just tried that - made the width smaller (no change) then tried setting the width to the same as the cell width (also no change)...

Comment: Nope smth like CGRectMake(x,y,113,500).See,I don't know why but your content size is bigger then the size of the collection view.Just try to ovverride this in your controller,although this method should be overridden only for custom layouts.

Comment: in the worst case you can position cells by yourself in cellForItemAtIndexPath.It is not that difficult.

Comment: I just did something almost identical, but it doesn't work. It seems the layout overrides this  kind of thing....

Comment: Do you mean you overrode contentSize?Or changed cell's frame?

Comment: I've tried both - neither works. Most recently I tried cellForItem...         CGRect tmpFrame=cell.frame;
        tmpFrame.origin.y=(indexPath.row*cell.frame.size.height);
        tmpFrame.origin.x=0;
        cell.frame=tmpFrame;

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using StoryBoard like this:

1. In the Attribute Inspector, make sure the CollectionView layout is "Flow" and Scroll Direction is set to "Vertical"
2. Choose the Size Inspector (The "ruler" tab)
3. Adjust the LEFT and RIGHT values under the "Section Insets" portion, Increasing the values should adjust the "gaps" between the left and right of the cell. Once the gap becomes too large to accommodate multiple cells in one row, the collection view will automatically adjust to one cell per row.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry - doesn't work. If my Cell is 113w and my CollectionView is 113w, changing the Section Insets changes the size of the cell....try it